# Hololens replaces GameObjects after spatialmap scan

Tags: anchor, hololens, gameobject

I have made an application for the hololens with the holotoolkit. The app gets an array with 3D positions and spawns GameObjects based on these positions.
After walking a bit in the room and change some realworld objects (maybe open a door or something) the hololens will recognized it, then a window opens and says 'Finding your space' and all of the GameObjects are in the wrong position.

How can I use SpaitalMapping, but not allow to replace the GameObjects i place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After walking a bit in the room and change some realworld objects (maybe open a door or something) the hololens will recognized it

I'm not sure the details of the changes you made on realworld objects, but some changes in the real world may have a great impact on the lighting conditions. For example, after opening an outward door in a dimly lit room. a lot of daylight will enter the room.

Lighting can make a difference in the visual features that HoloLens detects. So changeable lighting conditions might cause HoloLens to lose tracking.

Besides, in environments where the visual features change because most objects move, will also cause the same problem.

I recommend that you try the steps in [I see a message that says Finding your space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-faq#i-see-a-message-that-says-finding-your-space) to fix this problem. In short,  make sure your artificial lighting conditions and WiFi signal are stable and try moving more slowly.